# Control.Value VS x=Control.Value performance

Tags: .net

In case we have to use a value inside a loop e.g.:

```
for n=0 to 10000
    if Datagridview1(0,n).value = datagridview1(1,0).value then ...
next
```

is there any performance issue instead of using

```
dim x=datagridview1(1,0).value
for n=0 to 10000
    if Datagridview1(0,n)=x then ...
next
```

?

Comment: Can you provide compiling code? In general, if you have two horses and you want to know which is faster, race your horses. (E.Lippert)

Comment: There will be some overhead because you're calling a function 10,000 times.  Whether it's _significant_ or not depends on the time spent in that function _relative to the entire program_.

Comment: But you are asking us if there is a performance issue, i ask you: do you have a performance issue?

Comment: I can't understant Scmelter's blame. I provided a simplified example. What other? I mean what is the good practice, because I am asking my self  every time I have such a case?

Comment: His first comment was quoting from [this blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).  Essentially, yes it _might_ be faster to cache it outside of the loop.  But if what you're doing in the loop is only 0.1% of the time of the overall algorithm, do you care?  Either way, the compiler might optimise it for you anyway - to find out whether something is faster or not depends on a bit more context, and can be affected by the environment in which it is running etc.  Only _you_ can do objective testing of which is faster in _your_ environment.

Comment: "what is the good practice" If the value cannot change within the loop then it's perfectly valid to store the value in a variable rather than recalculating it each time.  The point is it may or may not make a significant difference.  Are you opposed to doing so?  Why would you _not_ do that?

Comment: I use a main common library to implement basic methods for my current and future projects. Some times will be called thousands of times, so I mind about good practices as all this methods accumulate workload from year to year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in general it's more work if you have to do something 10000 times than doing it only once. So of course this is more efficient:

```
Dim x As Object = datagridview1(2,2).Value
For n As Int32 = 0 to 10000
    If a = x Then
        ' ... '
    End If
Next
```

because it only has to lookup the value once instead of 10000 times.

But as commented, "whether it's significant or not depends on the time spent in that function relative to the entire program". What's usually more important is to keep your code readable. And in this case you can even improve readability by using a variable instead of always `datagridview1(2,2).Value` if you'd used meaningful variable names.

In general, you can measure performance with the [`System.DiagnosticsStopWatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)